# Relative spectrum of a quasi-coherent algebra.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

I'm working out the notion of spectrum of a quasi-coherent algebra over a scheme.

$\require{AMScd}$
Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a scheme and $\mathcal A$ a quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_X$-algebra, i.e. a sheaf of ring $\mathcal A$ together with a morphism $\mathcal O_X \to \mathcal A$ making it a quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_X$-module. Then from the previous morphism, for every *affine* open subset $U$ of $X$, we have
$$ \mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A(U)) \to U.$$
Taking another *affine* open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $V \subseteq U$, the diagram
$$\begin{CD}
  @. V \\
 @. @VVV \\
\mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A(U)) @>>> U
\end{CD}$$
admit the limit $\mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A(U)) \times_U V \simeq \mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A (U) \otimes_{\mathcal O_X (U)} \mathcal O_X(V)) = \mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A(V))$, the last equality because of the quasi-coherence of $\mathcal A$. So the arrow $\mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A(V)) \to \mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A(U))$ is an open immersion and we can define the relative spectrum as the glueing
$$ \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathcal A := \mathrm{colim}_{\mathcal I}\,\mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A(-))$$
where $\mathcal I$ is the opposite category of *affine* open subset of $X$.

**Then**, it is said in my notes that for all affine open subset $U$ of $X$, one have
$$ \boxed{\mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A(U)) = \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathcal A \times_X U,}$$
which I can't see.
Obviously, the map $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathcal A \to X$ being defined by the universal property of colimits on the maps $\mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A(U)) \to U \to X$, we have a commutative square
$$\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Spec}\,(\mathcal A(U)) @>>> U \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathcal A @>>> X.
\end{CD}$$
However, I don't see why it is cartesian...

Comment: Use the functorial construction of the relative spectrum (EGA I, §9), it makes life easier. No computations are necessary, and the fiber product statement follows immediately from the definition (more generally, if $f : Y \to X$ is a morphism, then $\mathrm{Spec}_X(A) \times_X Y = \mathrm{Spec}_Y(f^* A)$ since both sides represent the same functor).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I can't find it. I have the numdam version of EGA, maybe are you talking about another edition ?

Comment: Yes, Springer edition (1970).